# postgres column alias problem

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql, alias, heroku

As a newbie to Postgresql (I'm moving over because I'm moving my site to heroku who only support it, I'm having to refactor some of my queries and code. Here's a problem that I can't quite understand the problem with:

```
PGError: ERROR:  column "l_user_id" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t_id where l.user_id = 8 order by l2.geopoint_id, l_user_id ...
                                                             ^
```

...query:

```
   select distinct 
          l2.*, 
          l.user_id as l_user_id, 
          l.geopoint_id as l_geopoint_id 
     from locations l 
left join locations l2 on l.geopoint_id = l2.geopoint_id 
    where l.user_id = 8 
 order by l2.geopoint_id, l_user_id = l2.user_id desc
```

clause "l.user_id as l_user_id, l.geopoint_id as l_geopoint_id" was added because apparently postgres doesn't like order clauses with fields not selected. But the error I now get makes it look like I'm also not getting aliasing. Anybody with postgres experience see the problem?

I'm likely to have a bunch of these problems -- the queries worked fine in mySql...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can not use expression with an alias in order by. Only plain aliases work there. Your query should look like this:

```
   select distinct 
          l2.*, 
          l.user_id as l_user_id, 
          l.geopoint_id as l_geopoint_id 
     from locations l 
left join locations l2 on l.geopoint_id = l2.geopoint_id 
    where l.user_id = 8 
 order by l2.geopoint_id, l.user_id = l2.user_id desc;
```

I assume you mean that `l2.user_id=l.user_id` ought to go first.

[This is relevant message](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2005-10/msg00208.php) on PostgreSQL-general mailing list. The following is in the [documentation of `ORDER BY` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY):

> Each expression can be the *name or
>   ordinal number of an **output
>   column*** (SELECT list item), or it
>   can be an *arbitrary expression formed
>   from **input-column** values*.

So no aliases when expression used.

Comment: OK -- that makes sense, in light of the rule, but not entirely intuitive to someone who has been using mySql for years. I'll try it in code...

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same problem using functions from fuzzystrmatch - particularly the levenshtein function.  I needed to both sort by the string distance, and filter results by the string distance.  I was originally trying:

```
SELECT thing.*, 
levenshtein(thing.name, '%s') AS dist 
FROM thing 
WHERE dist < character_length(thing.name)/2 
ORDER BY dist
```

But, of course, I got the error "column"dist" does not exist" from the WHERE clause.  I tried this and it worked:

```
SELECT thing.*, 
(levenshtein(thing.name, '%s')) AS dist 
FROM thing 
ORDER BY dist
```

But I needed to have that qualification in the WHERE clause.  Someone else in this question said that the WHERE clause is evaluated before ORDER BY, thus the column was non-existent when it evaluated the WHERE clause.  Going by that advice, I figured out that a nested SELECT statement does the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT thing.*, 
     (levenshtein(thing.name, '%s')) AS dist 
     FROM thing 
     ORDER BY dist
) items 
WHERE dist < (character_length(items.name)/2)
```

Note that the "items" table alias is required and the dist column alias is accessible in the outer SELECT because it's unique in the statement.  It's a little bit funky and I'm surprised that it has to be this way in PG - but it doesn't seem to take a performance hit so I'm satisfied.

Comment: Note that there is no *guarantee* that an ORDER BY clause in the subquery will cause the final result to be in that order, although with this particular query I'm not aware of any optimizations which would do otherwise.  It would be safer, though, to move the ORDER BY clause out of the subquery where it is explicitly affecting the final result.

Comment: @kgrittn. Thanks for the pointer but, whenit worked for me by giving the order by clause inside the sub query. Pls provide info if any specific scenarios.

Comment: @kartik-narayana-maringanti It probably will work as intended every time _now_ -- the question is whether you want to leave it in a state where a new release might break the ordering, or write it in the form guaranteed to work both now and in future releases.  If you're OK with counting on undocumented implementation details rather than the documented approach, you're fine.

Answer (score 4):

You have:

```
order by l2.geopoint_id, l_user_id = l2.user_id desc
```

in your query. That's illegal syntax. Remove the `= l2.user_id` part (move it to `where` if that's one of the join conditions) and it should work.

**Update** Below select (with `= l2.user_id` removed) should work just fine. I've tested it (with different table / column names, obviously) on Postgres 8.3

```
select distinct 
       l2.*, 
       l.user_id as l_user_id, 
       l.geopoint_id as l_geopoint_id 
  from locations l 
  left join locations l2 on l.geopoint_id = l2.geopoint_id 
 where l.user_id = 8 
 order by l2.geopoint_id, l_user_id desc
```

Comment: I changed the references to non-aliased ones, and all is fine. Changes to what you suggest did not change the alias problem, though: it still does not like the l_user_id alias...

Comment: This is not equivalent of the query in question. "order by l_user_id = l2.user_id desc" means that rows where l.user_id and l2.user_id are equal have to go first.

Answer (score 1):

"was added because apparently postgres doesn't like order clauses with fields not selected"

"As far as order by goes - yes, PostgresQL (and many other databases) does not allow ordering by columns that are not listed in select clause."

Just plain untrue.

=> SELECT id FROM t1 ORDER BY owner LIMIT 5;

### id

30
 10
 20
 50
 40
(5 rows)